# Struts 2 Jars Conflict

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts-config

My struts 2 tile application was working fine. 
But after adding the struts2-jquery-plugin library jar, I am getting the following error:

"SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]"

My libraries structure is:

- antlr-2.7.6
- commons-beanutils-1.7.0
- commons-collections-3.1
- commons-digester-1.7
- commons-fileupload-1.2.1
- commons-io-1.3.2
- commons-lang-2.3
- commons-logging-1.1
- freemarker-2.3.13
- hsqldb
- jta-1.1
- log4j-1.2.15
- ognl-2.6.11
- slf4j-api-1.5.8
- slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8
- struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.6
- struts2-core-2.1.6
- struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.1
- struts2-tiles-plugin-2.1.6
- tiles-api-2.1.2
- tiles-compat-2.1.2
- tiles-core-2.1.2
- tiles-jsp-2.1.2
- tiles-servlet-2.1.2
- xwork-2.1.2

I am unable to find the jars/classes which are getting conflict.

And I want to know what is the best way to overcome such conflict.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflicts are coming from using a version of the jQuery plugin that doesn't work with the version of S2 you're using. 3.5.1 of the s2 jQuery plugin requires S2 2.3.8, as [its POM shows](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jgeppert/struts2/jquery/struts2-jquery/3.5.1/struts2-jquery-3.5.1.pom) (in `struts2-jquery`, the plugin's parent project).

You cannot arbitrarily mix-and-match versions of libraries; you must respect dependencies unless you are certain they're compatible. It's why we have tools like Maven.

One way to highlight possible conflicts is to use `mvn dependency:tree` and see where there are multiple versions of the same library.

Comment: Thanks Dave for replying. But I want to know that Is there any struts dojo or jquery plugin which is compatible with struts2 version 2.1.6 ?

Comment: I found the compatible version. Anyway +1 for the input Dave. Thanks!